# How to calculate the total of traveled time

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I need to get a `NSString` that displays a total of traveled time using 2 `NSStrings`

I have

```
NSString *origin = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"5:30"];
NSString *destiny = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"6:00"];
```

The problem is I don't know how to format this `NSStrings` to `NSDate` and do `destiny - origin` so the output would be a new `NSString` that says `30 minutes`

**EDIT:** I've just investigate a little about the `NSDateFormatter` but if I use it:

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate * mydate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:origin];
```

`NSDate` returns me a `nil` Is there something wrong?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Did you investigate `NSDateFormatter`? That's going to be the answer as it converts between dates and strings (in both directions). But if you looked at it and couldn't see how for some reason then perhaps there's a more specific question on that we could be answering?

Comment: What you need is `NSDateFormatter`, documentation is here:https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: `NSDateFormatter` is not the right solution if all you have is two times. Where did the two time strings come from? Why are you using strings to track time?

Comment: @rmaddy that was my first thought too

Comment: my answer: just do it. you have to do it the hard way. parse the string. convert it to some data format. define a subtract function. subtract the dates. write a function that converts the result to something like "30 minutes".

Comment: @Flipacholas `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"5:30"]` looks odd. I would replace it with `@"5:30"`. The same for the other string...

Comment: @Flipacholas regarding your recent EDIT. Yes, there is something wrong. `NSDateFormatter` just cannot do what you want to do, as rmaddy already pointed out too. You have to parse the string manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *origin = @"5:30";
NSString *destiny = @"6:00";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"H:mm"];

NSDate *originDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:origin];
NSDate *destinyDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:destiny];

NSTimeInterval interval = [destinyDate timeIntervalSinceDate:originDate];
NSDate *intervalDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:originDate ];

NSDateComponents *comps =[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSMinuteCalendarUnit
                                                         fromDate:originDate
                                                           toDate:intervalDate
                                                          options:0];
```

Now the NSDateComponents will hold the difference in minutes

```
NSLog(@"%ld", [comps minute]);
```

will log `30`

If you would like the hours and minutes, you can do

```
NSString *origin = @"5:30";
NSString *destiny = @"7:00";

// .... 

NSDateComponents *comps =[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: (NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit)
                                                         fromDate:originDate
                                                           toDate:intervalDate
                                                          options:0];
```

Now comps will hold the 90 minutes as 1 hour and 30 minutes.

```
NSLog(@"%ld %ld", [comps hour],[comps minute]);
```

logs `1 30`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *origin = @"5:30";
NSString *destiny = @"6:00";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"H:mm"];
NSDate *originDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:origin];
NSDate *destinyDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:destiny];

NSTimeInterval diffInSeconds = [destinyDate timeIntervalSinceDate:originDate];
NSTimeInterval diffInMinutes = diffInSeconds / 60;
NSString *minutesString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", diffInMinutes];
```

Comment: your code using HH:mm was returning nil because HH expects a two digit hour and your dates only contained one digit.